# Supporting Multiple Screens in android?

Tags: android, android-screen-support

In my application, I am setting multiple screen support. In my layout am using layout-normal it supports 320x480 and 480X720hdpi(I think, because it takes it from layout-normal)every layout fit to both resolution perfectly, But pop up window not fit for 480X720 resolution.

Please refer my image **320x480 screen image** and **480x720 screen image** will know the problem. How to solve the problem.

[image: 320X480 Screen]

[image: 480x720 Screen]

1.320X480 Screen
2.480x720 Screen

Comment: This link will help http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Have you given fixed height and width for the popup dialog you created?

Comment: @Nirali ya am gave fixed height and width.

Comment: So it will create problem with different resolutions. Don't give fix height and width.

Comment: @Nirali can i set it as wrap content.is it right one to fix this problem.

Comment: Yes use wrap_content for height and width

Comment: @Nirali ya its working and its not possible to set a required size of popup window.

Comment: @Nirali all its working in fine way thank you.am set a layout width and height through **shape**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add you layout to every folder like

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation
```

In Manifest add support-screens

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
                  android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
                  android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="integer"
                  android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
                  android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
```

For more info check this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: ya thank you am using like that way only.but the problem in popup window only.now that thing also solved.

Comment: just adding copies of the very same xml file to different layout folders won't do any good.