# Designing the layout for 5 inch to 10inch tablet in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I have created the layout for nexus 7 thst is 7 inch tablet but i want to develop the same layout for 5 inch to 10 inch tablet 
my code is working porperly on nexus 7 but not on other tablet so is there any solution for this

below is the XML code

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ui_logo"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tc_mangClass"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tc_mangClass"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
            android:fontFamily="font/Roboto-Light.ttf"
            android:text="@string/tc_mangClass"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/mangClass" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ui_uname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tc_mangClass"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/user"
            android:drawablePadding="28dp"
            android:fontFamily="font/Roboto-Light.ttf"
            android:hint="@string/uname"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/whitedul"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ui_upass"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ui_uname"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/password"
            android:drawablePadding="28dp"
            android:fontFamily="font/Roboto-Light.ttf"
            android:hint="@string/upass"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/whitedul"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ui_ucode"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ui_upass"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/edu"
            android:drawablePadding="14dp"
            android:fontFamily="font/Roboto-Light.ttf"
            android:hint="@string/ucode"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/whitedul"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/ui_rember"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ui_ucode"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:checked="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ui_remText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ui_ucode"
            android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:text="@string/remText"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:textSize="@dimen/remtext" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ui_login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/ui_rember"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ui_rember"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_back"
            android:fontFamily="font/Roboto-ThinItalic.ttf"
            android:text="@string/login"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/tsize" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ui_fpass"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ui_login"
            android:layout_marginLeft="175dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:text="@string/fpass"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />


        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="27dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ui_login"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
            android:background="@color/white">

        </View>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ui_codeFinder"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ui_fpass"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/divider"
            android:text="@string/scfind"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to declare the layout for 7'inch tablet Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763065/how-to-declare-the-layout-for-7inch-tablet-android)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Supporting Multiple Screens in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15269652/supporting-multiple-screens-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution to give height and width to your views in dp, and dp should be created in dimens.xml file, in layout_height and layout_width give reference from @dimens file

Check this:
[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28939905/android-which-values-folders-i-have-created-for-support-all-resolutions-include/28940014#28940014)